# Having trouble with sqlsrv on CentOS 7. Looking for assistance or possibly ODBC alternative

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv, php-5.6

I'm having a try at connecting to a MSSQL DB using PHP on a Linux system.

Using `tsql -S <dbConfig>` or `tsql -H <dbHost>` successfully connects to the database (with user credentials of course). However, using the same host and config within PDO returns a failed to connect to host adapter error.

The issue seems to be living somewhere between PHP PDO and, I'm assuming freetds.

The debug looks like this:

```
 PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
 SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (MYHOST.database.windows.net) (severity 9)
        in Connector.php line 55

at PDO->__construct('dblib:host=MYHOST.database.windows.net;dbname=RecipeDB;charset=utf8', 'MYUSER@MYHOST', 'MYPASSWORD', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php line 55
at Connector->createConnection('dblib:host=MYHOST.database.windows.net;dbname=RecipeDB;charset=utf8', array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => 'MYHOST.database.windows.net', 'database' => 'RecipeDB', 'username' => 'MYUSER@MYHOST', 'password' => 'MYPASSWORD', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'remoteRecipes'), array('0', '2', '0', false)) in SqlServerConnector.php line 32
at SqlServerConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => 'MYHOST.database.windows.net', 'database' => 'RecipeDB', 'username' => 'MYUSER@MYHOST', 'password' => 'MYPASSWORD', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'remoteRecipes')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 61
at ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'd managed to remove the line containing `[global]` from my /etc/freetds.conf file. Once I replaced it PDO was able to make a call to the database.

Below is what it looks like for me:

```
[global]
# TDS protocol version
 ; tds version = 4.2
 tds version = 8.0
 client charset = UTF-8

# Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
# (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
   debug flags = 0xffff

# Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

# If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
# is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
# Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
text size = 64512

[testConnection]
    host = MYHOST.database.windows.net
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```